# Using numba in a method to randomize matrices

Tags: numba

I'm still not very familiar with **numba** and my problem is that I have the piece of code bellow that I use for randomize the edges of graphs.

This code is simply used to swap some edges in a connectivity matrix given the number of desired swaps and a seed for the random number generator.

My problem is that  when I try to use it with **numba** to speed it up I did not menage to run it. The error it returns is also pasted bellow.

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def _randomize_adjacency_wei(A, n_swaps, seed):
    
    np.random.seed(seed)
    
    # Number of nodes
    n_nodes = A.shape[0]
    # Copy the adj. matrix
    Arnd    = A.copy()
    
    # Choose edges that will be swaped
    edges = np.random.choice(n_nodes, size=(4, n_swaps), replace=True).T
    
    #itr = range(n_swaps)
    #for it in tqdm(itr) if verbose else itr:
    it = 0
    for it in range(n_swaps):
        i,j,k,l = edges[it,:]
        if len(np.unique([i,j,k,l]))<4:
            continue
        else:
            # Old values of weigths
            w_ij,w_il,w_kj,w_kl=Arnd[i,j],Arnd[i,l],Arnd[k,j],Arnd[k,l]
            # Swaping edges
            Arnd[i,j]=Arnd[j,i]=w_il
            Arnd[k,l]=Arnd[l,k]=w_kj
            Arnd[i,l]=Arnd[l,i]=w_ij
            Arnd[k,j]=Arnd[j,k]=w_kl
    return Arnd
```

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function unique at 0x7f1a1c03b0d0>) found for signature:
 
 >>> unique(list(int64)<iv=None>)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload in function 'np_unique': File: numba/np/arrayobj.py: Line 1915.
    With argument(s): '(list(int64)<iv=None>)':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
   Unknown attribute 'ravel' of type list(int64)<iv=None>
   
   File "../../../home/vinicius/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/arrayobj.py", line 1918:
       def np_unique_impl(a):
           b = np.sort(a.ravel())
           ^
   
   During: typing of get attribute at /home/vinicius/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/arrayobj.py (1918)
   
   File "../../../home/vinicius/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/arrayobj.py", line 1918:
       def np_unique_impl(a):
           b = np.sort(a.ravel())
           ^

  raised from /home/vinicius/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1071

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function unique at 0x7f1a1c03b0d0>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-165-90ffd30fe0e8> (19)


File "<ipython-input-165-90ffd30fe0e8>", line 19:
def _randomize_adjacency_wei(A, n_swaps, seed):
    <source elided>
        i,j,k,l = edges[it,:]
        if len(np.unique([i,j,k,l]))<4:
        ^
```

Thanks in advance,
Vinicius

Comment: np.unique isn't supported using lists as input. You can just use a set or check if the 4 variables are not the same (by if conditions).

Comment: Or you could use `np.unique(edges[it,:])`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, you are passing a list to `np.unique()` but this is not supported by Numba.

Modifying the code this way:

```
    i, j, k, l = e = edges[it, :]
    if len(np.unique(e)) < 4:
        ...
```

The following example doesn't produce any errors:

```
>>> A = np.random.randint(0, 5, (8,8))
>>> r = _randomize_adjacency_wei(A, 4, 33)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved the problem